# How to get the image id via a button to use it in views.py?

Tags: python, html, django

I am pretty new to django and coding in generall, I'm trying to build an Instagram clone.. so my question is.. how can I comment on a post that is on the newsfeed(list of all uploaded images by every user), without leaving the newsfeed?

So my approach is to give every send button an id? or name? and somehow use it inside my views.py

views.py:

```
def newsfeed(request):
    images = Image.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        c_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = c_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.owner = request.user
            new_comment.image = #here should be something that points to the image i'm commenting on
            c_form.save()
            return redirect('upload_img:newsfeed')

    else:
        c_form = CommentForm()


    context = {'images_temp': images, 'c_form': c_form}
    return render(request, 'newsfeed.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s comments on %s image' % (self.owner, self.image.owner)
```

newsfeed.html:

```
{% for image in images_temp %}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ c_form|crispy }}
    <button name="{{ image.image }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: are you trying to save a comment in database and retrieving that comment in the newsfeed without page refresh ?

Comment: No, I'm trying to save a comment to the database.. but I don't know where to get the id of the Post/Image while staying on the newsfeed.. so the Images are coming from Image.objects.all() and get passed in the newsfeed.html via {% for image in images_temp %}, and every image object has a comment form with a submit button, so how do i know what post/form was used.. so that i get the connection from comment and Post/Image? i hope that makes sense. thanks in advance. @Ahtisham

Comment: I tried it but didn't worked.. but I solved it, just not sure if that's best practice.. I put a hidden input filed with the post id and pass it to the view when ever a comment is submited by the user.. and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can add id to every comment in a way that makes them unique like adding the post pk and the number of the comments in the post like

```
POST 6
comment-1
comment-2
comment-3 <-- This comment would have the id P6C3
```

And after that in your redirect function you can simply do

```
redirect(newsfeed + '#' + comment_id)
```

This would scroll into the new comment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem is how do i get the Post id? so this is the URL i am at http://localhost:8000/upload_img/newsfeed/..
I know how to do it when I am on this URL http://localhost:8000/upload_img/detail/26 because here ist the Post id = 26.
But how do i get the id 26 on the newsfeed. I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is stored on the database, if you don't have a different id that you assign to each post it is pk by default which is `post.pk`